# opencv - haarcascades not working for eye detection

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I have been following the tutorial [**here**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html) for object tracking for both the face and eyes through a webcam using opencv. The problem is that even though the face detection works using `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml`, i am receiving no results for eye detection using `haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml` (or any other haarcascade for eye detection). Following the code, i noticed a few errors that would not allow my code to run, so i modified to tutorials source. 
From this:

```
if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
 if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1;};
```

To this:

```
 eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name );
 face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ;
```

This was the only modification made in the source.

**NOTE**

->all of the haarcascades are in the source directory.

->only some of the haarcascades provide results `haarcascade_frontalface_alt` & `haarcascade_profile`

-> I have tried the other available haarcascades for eye detection including `haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml,` `haarcascade_eye haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml`, `haarcascade_mcs_righteye.xml`, `haarcascade_mcs_lefteye.xml` `haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_small.xml`, `haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_small.xml`, `haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml`, `haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml`

If anybody has a solution to my problem that would be greatly appreciated! The source is available through the Opencv documentation [**here**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html)

Comment: > If anybody has a solution to my problem.

I'm not really sure what your problem is. "It doesn't work" is hard to solve...

Comment: Well, the problem is that a lot of haarcascades will not return any results, if i followed the tutorial verbatim, what could be a potential cause for for my `eyes_cascade` to not return any values?

Comment: Like i say. Without seeing some code, or an error message or something its pretty hard to solve something that's just "not working". Have you made sure all your file paths are correct for the ones that aren't working? that they are definitely where you think they are etc.

Comment: I just solved it after 10 hours of trial and error, the relative path to the xml only worked for a few of the haarcascades, but when i change the string path to their full paths, the haarcascades worked. I tried this also last night, and it did not work. I must of done something wrong.

Comment: @GPPK do you know of any reason why only a select few `.xml's` would work from the source directory? but all work from full path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i realized the answer to my problem, i had to use the full path for the `.xml` files and change the permission on my folder (grant all permission).In example:

`String face_cascade_name = "C:\\Opencv-2.4.9\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";`

Comment: yea, reporting back is important.

Comment: I know it was a simple bug, but still cannot seem to figure out why the absolute path worked for some but not all `.xml's`